# How to overcome "flooded" sound when singing?

Tags: voice

Lately I've been learning to sing, nothing fancy but I've noticed that I sound flooded (that's a word from google translate so I'm not sure if it's accurate. It feels like I have "stuff" in my nose that doesn't let the full sound come out.)

I hope someone understands what I mean since I'm not a native English speaker. It's hard for me to explain what's really going on.

Any tips on that?

Comment: It is a bit hard to understand what you mean, unfortunately. But if you are singing "though your nose" that is one problem right there at least. One suggestion is to try and find some basic singing tutorials on line.

Comment: *How* do you notice?  Does it sound bad to *you* when singing, or does it sound bad when you *record* it and listen to it?  Does it sound bad to *others*?  Efficient singing does not necessarily give a good impression of the results to the singer himself.

Comment: That sounds like a clear enough description to me, but, gosh, I have no idea.  I've never heard of that problem before.  Are you certain you _don't_ have something clogging your nose?

Comment: I'm not singing through my nose, it's just like the sound doesn't want to resonate... I don't know how to describe it more accurately. I asked a friend as well if I sound "flooded" and she said yes, so it's not just my impression. And this problem is persistent it's not like I woke up one day and sound like that, every time I record myself I hear that same thing that makes me repulsed about my voice :/

Comment: you should do a recording of you singing put it on youtube and include it in your post its impossible to tell without hearing you...do you have asthma or copd?

Comment: Try breathing in some menthol and eucalyptus mixture (from the chemist) in steamy hot water for five minutes. If this helps then you've found the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get singing lessons from a qualified voice teacher, in person. You need the immediate feedback of singing for someone who can listen to what you are doing and patiently teach you to how sing differently and improve your tone. There is no point in trying to solve this problem by reading a written description of it online.

Comment: I think if we heard the problem we could diagnose what he was facing in this situation. You don't need to go to elementary  school to learn to color in the lines.

Answer (score 1):

I have a lot of phlegm that builds up while I'm singing.  There are a few things you can do to prevent this, especially on days of a performance.

1. Stay hydrated.  The mucous builds up as a result of your throat becoming dry and your body responding.
2. Avoid dairy and overly sweet food and drink.  These will build up excess fluids, as well.
3. Exercise daily.  A strong cardiovascular system can help you achieve and hold fuller tones.

For singers, unlike players, practice isn't enough.  Physical discipline is required to achieve your best results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I second the rec for lessons. There are specific exercises which, practiced daily, will help you extend range and find the many things your voice is capable of without damage. There is really a lot to it. I play several instruments (guitar, clarinet, sax) reasonably well but singing was the longest journey for me. I started lessons some years ago, stopped, started again, and in the last year or so I find I have a voice that I can really use. It's been a big work, but well worth it.

There are so many small recommendations that people could make, but without actually hearing you it doesn't mean much and could even push you in the wrong direction. There is one thing I can say though. If it hurts or feels uncomfortable - stop. Your vocal chords are an incredible but sometimes quite delicate instrument. Take care of them. Technique really matters with singing, even more than other instruments.

Good luck.